# How to restore Outlining submenu that has disappeared from Visual Studio 2019 Pro context menu

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I was using outlining just fine, when suddenly it disappeared from the text editor context menu.  And I could not find the outlining submenu from within the Visual Studio menu bar either.

Comment: It's great that you solved your own problem and are willing to share the knowledge with the community, but questions posted here need to be answerable by _the community_, not just yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting Visual Studio solved this problem.  The Outlining submenu was again within the text editor context menu.

TIP:  Hovering mouse over outlining [-] box on left will shade the code between the constructs of the [-].  Try it!

Comment: Hi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)